# Code to loop through columns for specific value range

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I want a code which allows to loop through the columns of Sheet A, and columns which have values>0 would be copied to Sheet B. Did a code with help of some answers from the previous forum question but still having issues as it does not seem to work at the paste destination! Some help would be very much appreciated. The code is as follows:

```
Sub TestPasteColumnData3()

Dim lastcol As Long
Dim j As Long

    With Worksheets("WF - L12 (3)")
    lastcol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       For j = 3 To lastcol
        If CBool(Application.CountIfs(.Columns(j), ">0")) Then
            .Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(3)
        Else
            MsgBox ("No Value")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You keep pasting to column 3. Try:

```
.Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(j)
```

Comment: What do you get? Does your code ever reach this line?

Comment: Hi sorry it works now but it still pastes columns which has no values >0

Comment: Do the `COUNTIFS` as a formula in the sheet, and see if you get correct values. `=COUNTIFS(C:C,">0")`, `=COUNTIFS(D:D,">0")`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub TestPasteColumnData3()

Dim lastcol As Long
Dim j As Long

    With Worksheets("WF - L12 (3)")
    lastcol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       For j = 3 To lastcol
      'change >0 to <>0 and 3 to j        
      If CBool(Application.CountIfs(.Columns(j), "<>0")) Then
            .Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(j)
        Else
            MsgBox ("No Value")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Pl make 2 changes suggested above your code will work.

@Niva I am yet to find out basic reason of Countifs or CountA not giving desired results. For your immediate requirements you can use an additional program to delete blanks in Sheet1. Please make it Active Sheet and use the following program.

```
Sub DeleteBlankColumns()

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   'MsgBox lastColumn
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

   Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells

     lastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

    'MsgBox lastRow
   'Step1:  Declare your variables.
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim iCounter As Long
   'Step 2:  Define the target Range.
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))

   'Step 3:  Start reverse looping through the range.

    For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
   'Debug.Print iCounter
   'Step 4: If entire column is empty then delete it.
       Debug.Print Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0
       If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
       Columns(iCounter).Delete
       End If
  'Step 5: Increment the counter down
    Next iCounter
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Niva if you keep ">0" it will give false even for a non empty cell but "<>0" will correctly work and give true value for a non empty cell.

Comment: Sorry but it still does not work:/ Worksheet still remains blank after runing the code

Comment: @Niva It works for me. Should I upload sample file to drop box

Comment: I have uploaded sample file <https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kj3iehzp4f8mnr/copy_to_loop.xlsm?dl=0>

Comment: @Niva if dropbox does not suit you then pl suggest alternatives.

Comment: Hi sorry it works now but it still pastes columns which has no values >0

Comment: @Niva It is doing so because lastcol is coming 8 and despite the condition is checking correctly .Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(j) will print as per column no. only as such it is printing blank column. Someway is to be found out to decrement J if the column is empty which is rightly checked or some other way to resize the columns.

Comment: @Niva please ignore my previous comment.      ~CBool(Application.CountIfs(.Columns(j), "<>0"))~   It is giving True even for a non empty cell. This needs attention.

Comment: @Niva I am yet to find out basic reason of Countifs or CountA not giving desired results. For your immediate requirements you can use an additional program to delete blanks in Sheet1. I am editing my answer for the same.

Comment: hi sorry for the trouble but appreciate that you are helping out so much:) tried the code it does not seem to execute, columns start from C and row starts from row 5. Did the amendments to the range but still in vain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111602/discussion-between-skkakkar-and-niva).

Comment: @Niva can you join me in chat? If not possible I shall upload my sample file which works properly to dropbox or any other site suggested by you.

Comment: @Niva both programs columndata3 and deleteblankcolumns are working fine with me. Please ensure after running first program select sheet1 by selecting any cell in active area and then run deletebalnkcolumns. uploaded file link <https://www.dropbox.com/s/1q8q2qcwkuqkili/copy_to_loop_v2.xlsm?dl=0>

Answer (score 0):

Why use copy and paste? I try to avoid copy and paste because it relies on the OS's clipboard which can be used by other applications.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(j).value = Columns(j).value
```

also this:

```
Application.CountIfs
```

should be this:

```
Application.worksheetfunction.CountIf 'Note, don't need countifS for only 1 criteria
```

Also, not sure that you really need to convert it to a boolean.

Comment: Did the above but it still copies blank columns. I think it has something to do with the j variable because when i hardcode  it , the countif function works